# Hash takes more memory than list?

Tags: redis

Please help to choose how to store messages:

1)

```
SET msg:1 sender 12
SET msg:1 text "hello there"
SET msg:1 date 6278127367
SET msg:1 recpnt 88223
SET msg:1 viewed false
SET msg:2 sender 102
SET msg:2 text "blablabla"
SET msg:2 date 6278127643
SET msg:2 recpnt 523
SET msg:2 viewed false
SET msg:3 sender 16
SET msg:3 text "nice weather isntit"
SET msg:3 date 6278127432
SET msg:3 recpnt 48781
SET msg:3 viewed true
```

2)

```
LPUSH msg:1 12 "hello there" 6278127367 88234 false
LPUSH msg:2 523 "blablabla" 6278127367 4323 false
LPUSH msg:3 16 "nice weather isn't it" 6278127234 223 true
LPUSH fields sender text date recpnt viewed
```

SET seems easier to use than LIST, but will Redis store field names with every message and thus about **double** the memory usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I believe you meant to say hash and not set; the set data structure is not appropriate for what you are describing.

The two options you then have are:

1. Hash: a string-to-string map of data. If you imagine the key value is JSON data, your message as a hash will look something like this:

   ```
   msg:1 = {
     "sender": "12",
     "text":   "hello there",
     "date":   "6278127367",
     "recpnt": "88223",
     "viewed": "false"
   }
   ```

   You will notice that you can see clearly what value maps with what key; the data has some structure. [Hash look up](http://redis.io/commands/hget) is also constant time.
2. List: a linked list of strings. Again, imagining your data as JSON:

   ```
   msg:1 = ["12", "hello there", "6278127367", "88223", "false"]
   ```

   Now it's not clear what value maps to what field, is it? You would have to keep track of what index of the list stores which information, which adds complexity to your application. Also, [accessing an individual field](http://redis.io/commands/lrange) is no longer constant time.

From the two points above, **hash** seems more appropriate.

But what is the impact on space in choosing a hash table? Here is the size of both the hash and list (found using `DEBUG OBJECT <key>`) using the above message:

- List: 49 bytes
- Hash: 86 bytes (~1.75x)

The message was only 11 characters. What about one that is [tweet-sized (116 characters)](https://twitter.com/antirez/status/527460553338683392)?

- List: 143 bytes
- Hash: 174 bytes (~1.22x)

Yes, hash is going to be larger to store, but it's probably not going to be double the size in your average case.

So despite being a little larger, I still believe that **hash** is the correct data structure to use (unless, of course, your increased hosting bills are going to bankrupt you).

Comment: Exactly, but my most concern is memory footprint, since doubling of data means double RAM means double cost ($$) of hosting.

Comment: Maybe short property names is the way to save memory.